# How do I make this (own) trim() function work in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, trim

I have to do an [assignment](https://pastebin.com/SQ4eRe8Y), where I have to remove the spaces from the end and the front of a text. (I don't know if there are always one in the front or in the end.)

So for example if my input is **" Pls help me"** then my output has to be **"Pls help me"** (no space in the front.)
I cant use any more library that i'm using right now.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int *pIndexf; // pointer Index front (of the text)
int *pIndexe; // pointer Index end (of the text)

void trim(char source[], int size) {
  
  // Checking the array from the front
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
    if (source[i] == ' ') {
        pIndexf = &i;
        break;
    }
  } 

  // Checking the array from behind
  for (int i = strlen(source)-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (source[i] == ' ') {
       pIndexe = &i;
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  char source[31] = {" Random text "}; // the array where i store the text i have to manipulate
  char goal[31]; // this is where the trimmed text should be

  trim(source, 31);
  
// Here i would add the source array's elements to the goal list without the spaces in a loop
}
```

It would be better if I could use the pointers to point back to the `main` function instead of using them as a global variable.

I hope my problem is understandable.

ps.: I don't really understand pointers.

Comment: Small help:  Pls note that "The function takes two parameters: a source array (this contains the string with the space) and a destination array (this contains the string without the space)"  -- I only see "source[]" in your trim() function.  That and integer 'size'.  Needs a "dest[]"

Comment: Small help2: you're off-track saving the address of index i (&i) -- it will always have the same address.  You can safely dump both your int pointers (pIndexf, etc) they won't serve you.  You may want to save index i for your solution, yes, but you would do that with another integer variable, ie:  "int save_i;"    Hint:  you can create a solution to this problem without adding any pointers:  it can all be done by using integer variables to access char array offsets.

Comment: OT: Assignment suggests `trim( src, dest );`. That would be opposite the Standard Library's convention, like `strcpy()`, `strcat()`, ..., whose arguments are `dest, src`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment says that the function `trim()` must take the source and destination arrays, so the function must do that.

The result of trimming is a string which may be as long as the source string or shorter, but never longer. Thus, the caller must always provide a destination array which is at least the size of the source array. With this usage requirement, there is no need to know the exact size of the destination array.

Also, there is no need to know the size of the source array since the C string will be zero-terminated.

Since standard library functions use the convention that the destination parameter comes before the source, the `trim()` function may as well follow the same convention. For the same reason, a pointer to the resulting string may be returned so the function can be used in composed expressions.

For the implementation itself, a strategy could be:

1. Find the length of the source string
2. From the end of the source string, find the first non-space character (if any is present).
3. From the beginning of the string, find the first non-space character.
4. Copy characters from the first to the last non-space characters to the destination string
5. Terminate the destination string with a zero character.

Following this, an implementation is:

```
#include <string.h>

char *trim(char *dest, const char *src)
{
   size_t end = strlen(src);                             // Step 1
   while(end > 0 && src[end-1] == ' ') end--;            // Step 2
   size_t begin = 0;
   while(begin < end && src[begin] == ' ') begin++;      // Step 3
   size_t dest_index = 0;
   while(begin < end) dest[dest_index++] = src[begin++]; // Step 4
   dest[dest_index] = 0;                                 // Step 5
   return dest;
}
```

Notice that `end` points one past the last non-space character, not at the last non-space character itself. This allows for correct handling of the corner cases (empty string or a string having all spaces) where `end` will be zero.

Example of usage:

```
const char src[] = " Pls help me";
char dest[sizeof(src)];
trim(dest, src);
```

Comment: Sorry, if im really dumb, but i don't understand so many things. 
1. Why is the function is a pointer? Can i do such things?
2. With the first and the second ```while``` loop are you doing anything besides just iterating? You are not writing into the `dest` array or any variable

Although thank you for your time and answer! 
3. Where is ```size_t``` declared, isn't that a function?

Comment: @Lolis4TheWin 1. Not sure what you mean. The function returns a pointer for convenience, e.g. `printf("Result: %s\n", trim(dest, src));`. 2. These loops modify `end` and `begin` indices to their right value 3. `size_t` is defined in various headers, e.g. `string.h`. It is an unsigned integer type large enough to hold the size of any object, e.g. the size of any array (you may think of it as an `unsigned`, but it has this additional guarantee on the range).

Comment: @Lolis4TheWin "_3. Where is size_t declared, isn't that a function_" You're probably confusing this with `sizeof` that used to be a "compile time operator" used to take the byte count of an object. Newer compilers also implement `sizeof` as a run-time operation to account for things like VLA's ("variable length arrays")...

Answer (score 2):

1. Your task is different. You need the size of the destination array to do not overflow it.
2. Do not use global variables as temporary objects in the functions.
3. Use the correct type for sizes.

```
char *trim(const char *source, char *dest, size_t size)
{
    const char *end = source;
    char *head = dest;
    if(source && dest && size)
    {   
        if(*source)
        {
            while(*(end + 1)) end++;
            while(end > source)
            {
                if(*end != ' ') break;
                else end--;
            }
            while(*source == ' ') source++;
            while(source <= end && --size) *dest++ = *source++;
        }
        *dest = 0;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand this code neither. 
Why the function is a pointer?
What are you checking for example in `if(*source)` statement? 
What is that `*(end + 1)` do? Why do you need a that to be a ponter?

Thank you for your time and response!

Comment: it returns pointer - for example you can use the result in the next function call,  `*(ptr + i)` === `ptr[i]`